# "android:layout_above" parameter in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, layout, android-relativelayout

First of all, here is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:background="@android:color/white">

    <LinearLayout [...]
                  android:layout_above"@+id/test">
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout [...]>

        <LinearLayout [...]
                      android:id="@+id/test"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This xml won't work...

Is there any option to do that? Setting the `android:layout_above` parameter to a view that's inside another one?

Comment: Well, he actually uses it in a RelativeLayout... But I think the target has to be a direct child of this RelativeLayout as well

Comment: So there is no chance to do that?

Comment: There is certainly another way to achieve what you want though, but you'll need to give more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified a bit of your code .. please try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:background="@android:color/white">

    <LinearLayout [...]
                      android:id="@+id/test">
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout [...]
                  android:layout_below"@+id/test">

        <LinearLayout [...]/>

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: For explanation.  Layouts process their children in a top down fashion so any layout_above, layout_below etc must refer to a view physically above it in the layout file.